# how do i change the color of my text in css?

Tags: css, text, colors

I want to change the color of two different types of descriptions. I want the text for two different descriptions to appear as two different colors. I want the text for the site description to appear as purple, and the text for the musician summary underneath each artist's name to appear as hot pink.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>My Music Website</title>
<style>
.musician-summary{
  color: blue;
}
#site-description{
  color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
</body>
<h1>My Music Website</h1>
<p id="site description"> Check out some of my favorite musical artists 
from around the world.</p>
<hr>
<h2 class="musician title">Stephane Wrembel</h2>
<p class="musician summary">His biggest influence and
  inspiration is Django Reinhardt. His music
is in the style of gypsy jazz. He learned
how to play directly from gypsies while living
with them for a few years.
Mysticism is a big theme in much of his
music. He plays many French standards
and his own compositions.</p>

<h2 class="musician title">Bjork</h2>
<p class="musician summary">Bjork has always shown a musical ability.
At the age of 11 she recorded her first album.
She gained fame outside of her country in the Icelandic punk band
The Sugarcubes, and later on went solo.
Her solo music is very ecclectic.
It ranges from hip-hop with some rhythms, classical, electronic, and she 
has been dubbed as the queen
of trip hop due to her use of hip hop beats.</p>

<h2 class="musician title">Sima Bina</h2>
<p class="musician summary">In Iran she is called Maestra Sima Bina. Her 
music is played in styles that are from and around Iran.</p>
```

Comment: You need to show how you think you're using this.

Comment: I included the entire code, John.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selector and class/ID in HTML are different; you have a space on ID and class, and using `-` in HTML.
Settle your class and ID with the same name as in CSS; `musician-summary` and `site-description`. 
By the way if you use space in class or Id names, it creates 2 classes/IDs